# IWebBrowser2 get from the native ActiveX control did not succeed

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms, browser

if (HiddenForm.configResponse != null)
    userId = HiddenForm.configResponse.id;
     ServiceActivityInterface remoteMethods = (ServiceActivityInterface)Activator.GetObject(typeof(TrayActivityInterfaces), ProHance.ProbeProperties.AgentProperties.ServiceRemotingUrl);
     string webConsoleToken = remoteMethods.GetWebConsoleToken(userId);
      managerWorkFlowLink = HiddenForm.workflowSettingConfigResponse.workflowUrl;
      byte[] dataByte = GenericHelper.ConvertToUTF8(HiddenForm.LoginName + "|" + webConsoleToken);
       byte[] encryptedBytes = EncryptionUtility.GetInstance().EncryptData(dataByte);
     string userAuthToken = GenericHelper.ConvertToBase64Encoding(encryptedBytes);
         ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = new System.Net.Security.RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(AcceptAllCertifications);
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(managerWorkFlowLink) && activeJob != null)
     {
     authToken = "Client/tokenauth.htm?mname=ChangeState&jobId=" + activeJob.jobId + "&stateId=" + activeJob.stateId + "&processId=" + activeJob.processId + "&clientAction=" + localuserAction + "&newtoken=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(userAuthToken);
    if (log.IsDebugEnabled) log.Debug("AuthToken:" + authToken);
     this.wbStateChange.Navigate(managerWorkFlowLink + authToken);
     }